# Force close Windows CE 5 app using C#

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

How do I go about force-closing an application on Windows CE 5.0, using C#? I've already tried `Application.Exit()` but this doesn't always kill all currently running threads.

I'd normally use `Environment.Exit()` but this is not available in CF, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the version of the CF you're using.  `Application.Exit` is the correct mechanism to exit the app, but your threads have to be handled as well.  In CF 2.0 and 3.5, set the `IsBackground` property to `true` on all created threads (just do it at creation time).  On CF 1.0, you have to manually add a flag into the containing class that the thread proc looks at periodically to know if it should exit.

Comment: Have you ever make a try with `Windows Embeeded 7` ? I run your sample code with CF 2, the form is closed, but the process doesn't end. If I launch my application from cmd, I have to `ctrl+C` to end the process. I think it is the same problem than [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671893/console-application-not-closing)