# Screen Doesn't clear on Terminate Application in Windows CE devices (Motorola WT4000 series)

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm running Windows CE 5.0 on an ARM processor device using .NET CF 3.5 with an application written in C#. (Scanner device)

I'm experiencing a problem where my application screen still persists even after i am killing the entire application using `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()`

PS: I am killing the application after timeout(say after 2 min if the device scree is idle). I have debugged the application with a break point on the line `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()`. It is killing the application and i am losing the connection in visual studion but, screen still persists on the device

Is there any of methods I can try and use or causes that would be making this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Application.Exit()?

Comment: Are you using Symbol.dll and Symbol.Barcode.dll? Maybe you are not disposing your scan-event-handlers the right way.

Comment: Two possibly issues: a) your app is still running, check with task manager or pps of itsutils (from xda developers site). or b) the app is killed but the screen does not update as you did something special with the shell.

Comment: @GaryWright I tried using it but Exit() is not even shown by intellisense

Comment: @etalon11 Thank you!! It might be helpful. I guess i should dispose the scan-event handlers before exiting the application.

Comment: The Application class exposes the static Exit method, so I'm not sure what you mean. Take a look at this SO question, it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967894/force-close-windows-ce-5-app-using-c-sharp